# Why `__rsub__` subtract in reverse?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have custom class that inherites from `list`. `CustomList` instances support subtraction between themselves and with regular `lists`. The corresponding elements of the  `CustomLists/lists` are subtracted. If one of the `CustomLists/lists` is shorter, the missing elements are considered as zeros.

```
from typing import Iterable, List


class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args: Iterable[int | float]):
        if args == ():
            super().__init__(*args)
        elif all(isinstance(a, (int, float)) for a in args[0]):
            super().__init__(*args)
        else:
            raise TypeError("CustomList instance can contain int and float datatypes only")

    def __sub__(self, other: List[int | float] | "CustomList") -> "CustomList":
        if isinstance(other, (self.__class__, list)):
            result = CustomList()
            for i in range(max(len(self), len(other))):
                if i < len(self) and i < len(other):
                    result.append(self[i] - other[i])
                elif i < len(self):
                    result.append(self[i])
                else:
                    result.append(other[i])
            return result

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__sub__(other)
```

`__sub__` works as expected, but when first operand is list (and `__rsub__` is called) - **subsctraction works in reverse**. Instead of `operand1 - operand2` it does `operand2 - operand1`.
For example:

`[1, 2, 3] - CustomList([2, 4, 6])` sholud be `CustomList([-1, -2, -3])` but I got `CustomList([1, 2, 3])` instead.
Why does this happen?

Comment: ...because you are calling `self.__sub__(other)`?

Comment: @InSync yes, because in  `__rsub__`'s  `self.__sub__(other)`  `other` is `list`. Have checked with `print(other)`

Comment: Mind you, `self.__sub__(other)` is also called when you do `self - other`. By returning a call to `__sub__()` from `__rsub__()` you are effectively converting `other - self` to `self - other`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__rsub__` is called when you do `list - CustomList`, let's say `L - myList`. when you define `__rsub__` the way you did, you are returning the result of `myList - L`. But subtraction is not commutative (`a - b != b - a`).

My recommended solution is to overload the negation operator (`__neg__`) to define what `- myList` is. and then modify `__rsub__` to return `- self.__sub__(other)`.

Here is the full solution:

```
from typing import Iterable, List


class CustomList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args: Iterable[int | float]):
        if args == ():
            super().__init__(*args)
        elif all(isinstance(a, (int, float)) for a in args[0]):
            super().__init__(*args)
        else:
            raise TypeError("CustomList instance can contain int and float datatypes only")

    def __sub__(self, other: List[int | float] | "CustomList") -> "CustomList":
        if isinstance(other, (self.__class__, list)):
            result = CustomList()
            for i in range(max(len(self), len(other))):
                if i < len(self) and i < len(other):
                    result.append(self[i] - other[i])
                elif i < len(self):
                    result.append(self[i])
                else:
                    result.append(other[i])
            return result

    def __neg__(self):
        result = CustomList()
        for val in self:
            result.append(-val)
        return result

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return - self.__sub__(other)
```

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] - CustomList([2, 4, 6])
[-1, -2, -3]
```

Comment: Note that this is not the most efficient as we're creating a new list in `__neg__` and then another one is `__sub__`. It would probably be more efficient to re-write `__rsub__` (and to use list comprehension in `__neg__`) but it gives you an idea

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe  to overload the negation operator `__neg__` too? Or another solution - to rewrite code from `__sub__` and paste it to `__rsub__`?

Comment: Both solution are perfectly fine. Overloading the `__neg__` is the more natural but as I said, in this case it is a little bit less efficient. copying `__sub__` into `__rsub__`  and reversing the logic would also work